# Semantic versioning and continuous deployment, conflicting idea in practice?

Tags: continuous-integration, nuget, .net-assembly, continuous-deployment, semantic-versioning

Some times the version information has to be embedded in the metadata of the output artifact. So, the version has to be decided at the build/compile time.

However, you can't call a version until you actually make a release in semantic versioning because the last digit has to be incremental.

E.g.

A release process has 6 steps. There are 2 builds coming through triggered from commit 1 and commit 2.

Before commit 1 finish the release process in step 6, you can't really determine what semantic commit 2/build 2 is going to be. If commit 1/build 1 fails, commit 2 / build 2 would be 1.0.0. If build 1 succeeds, build 2 would be 1.0.1.

If you are authoring nuget package or .net binaries, the version information would be already in the artifact itself and there's no way to change that.

Comment: Semantic versioning was pretty specifically invented to end the silly notion that building an assembly changes it.  Along with the usually ratty version number that generates.  Of course it doesn't, only changing the code changes it.  A programmer does that, not a build system.

Comment: @HansPassant ..... First of all, building an assembly OF COURSE changes the build number. From the compiler version to unpegged dependency, etc etc etc. Secondly, you can keep your pile of bureaucratic manual release process and army of release "managers" to yourself (Unless you work in a team of 1).

Comment: Semantic versioning does not use a build number.  It is major.minor.revision.  Keep your pants on.

Comment: @HansPassant Does it ever occur to you compilers have, I dunno, this thing called parameters? And depending on them the build, I dunno, might, come out different? Nah. Blasphemy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the incremental digit requirement as you describe it make sense?

Even if build 1 succeeds (thus validating v1.0.0 according to your description) you'd still not ship it if its result is DOA from the testing prospective (say the product keeps crashing).

So what would be the difference between v1.0.0 not deployed/shipped because it fails the build or because it's DOA? None as far as I can see.

I'd just drop that requirement and keep things simpler - each build has its own version based on the corresponding commit and some versions are not good (for whatever reason).

Comment: I'd increment it all day long with the build. Makes no difference to me either. Except I get people who is hell bent on "tagging production releases with semantic versions" and all that rubbish. I'll mark this as answer if I don't get anything better in a few days. (just to see if there's any other options.)

Comment: For those - just stick the sematic versioning as metadata, mapped to whatever actual versioning info comes from the build - it's cosmetic information anyways. Or pitch them named releases instead :)